# Grails Error: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes... After installing Spring Security Core

Tags: grails, spring-security, illegalstateexception

I just created a new grails-app,
everything was fine until I decided 
to install Spring Security Core.

After installing Spring Security Core 
doing an s2-quickstart and hitting 
grails run-app, it produced the 
following error:

```
URI
/test1/
Class
java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Anybody know how to fix this?
I would really appreciate it if 
you help. I have tried looking for 
answers in other websites, however 
I was unable to solve it. :)

BTW, I am using: 
Spring Security Core 1.2.4 
Grails 2.0.0.RC1

Comment: What controller does the URI /test1/ hit? What action is it taking? Any code you could post from the controller would help, as it's likely something within the controller or a service that isn't within the transactional session.

Comment: Hello, 
I just scaffolded all of my controllers, except for the ones produced by Spring Security Core itself. /test1/ is the name of my app. :)

Comment: I just tried creating a project, adding a domain class, generate-all on that domain, install spring-security-core, ran the s2-quickstart, and it worked fine. Have you tried grails clean?

Comment: Yup... Grails clean was actually the first thing that I did but with no luck.. I tried it again upon your request but still the same.. Hmm.. There must be something wrong somewhere, all my other apps seem to be running smoothly. Sorry I'm not really that familiar with servlets and stuff. :(

Comment: I was not able to solve the problem yet.. But looking around grails.jira... It seems like some people have the same problem as I am.. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-98

Comment: I just got this on Grails 2.2RC2 after run-app on a clean install. I ran run-app again and it worked. Haven't a clue why though...

Answer (score 16):

If you're using Maven, make sure you have this on your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

and in BuildConfig,groovy:

```
runtime ":webxml:1.4.1"
```

That solved the issue for me with Grails 2.2.0.

Comment: This fixed it for me in Grails 2.2.3, spring-security-core 1.2.7.3, thanks!!

Comment: Modifying the BuildConfig.groovy did not work for me, but adding "plugins.webxml=1.4.1" to the application.properties solved it. (I'm using ggts)

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if you're using an older version of Spring Security Core.  I hit this when upgrading from grails 1.3.7 (and spring security 1.1.3) to grails 2.0.0.  The fix was to change to spring-security-core 1.2 in application.properties:

```
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2
```

More info at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-98 as suggested by 황현정.

Comment: very nice, worked like a charm, but what is the `s2-quickstart` message that comes up from grails telling me to run that command?

Answer (score 1):

Try to register a RequestContextListener listener in web.xml file.

File : web.xml

```
<web-app>
   ...
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```